# Windows 7 Disk Management Spanned Volume vs Striped Volume

Tags: hard-drive

Im looking for a reason why a person would use a Spanned volume rather than a Striped volume?

If my understanding is correct

```
Striped:  Faster read/write speed than spanned, but I "assume" more wear+tear
Spanned:  No speed benefit like striped, but data is written sequentially and 
          fills up Drive1 before filling up Drive2, so it saves on wear+tear
```

Beyond that Im not sure if there is any other deciding factor on which to use.

Definition found below:

> A striped volume uses the free space on more than one physical hard
>   disk to create a bigger volume. Unlike a spanned volume, a striped
>   volume writes across all volumes in the stripe in small blocks,
>   distributing the load across the disks in the volume. The portions of
>   disk used to create the volume need to be the same size; the size of
>   the smallest free space included in the striped volume will determine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A spanned volume can be extended, but not a stripped.

A failure of eiher drive in a stripped volume will result in a total loss. You may be able get some data back from a spanned volume if the file is completly on one disk.

If you do not have a good backup system, then I suggest you don't use either option.

Comment: If you don't have a good backup system, I suggest you get yourself a good backup system. You either have suffered catastrophic data loss, or you have yet to.

Comment: ...or you can't suffer catastrophic data loss, because you don't care about your local data.

Answer (score 5):

A Span is not a RAID type, a Stripe is (RAID0).

You can build Stripes from Spans, but not Spans from Stripes. :)

Say you had 3 drives - 1 x 500GB drive and 2 x 250GB drives.

You can create a spanned volume across the 2 x 250GB drives, giving you 1 x 500GB volume.  You then use that in a Stripe with the 500GB drive so that you get the balance you need to take advantage of RAID0 (the Stripe).

Or use the Span + the 500GB drive to make a 500GB Mirror (RAID1).

I will say that this is general info about RAIDs, and I'm not sure Windows' inbuilt software RAID actually allows this, as I personally never use software RAIDs. :)